# NetSuite JournalEntry Rest URL

Tags: netsuite

I have a `REST` based `GET` url for getting all the accounts from `NetSuite`

```
https://rest.netsuite.com/rest/roles
```

HTTP Headers:

```
Authorization : NLAuth nlauth_account=1234,nlauth_email=myname@email.com,nlauth_signature=mypassword, nlauth_role=3
```

This is results set of accounts as json data.

I am working on connecting to Netsuite and create  Journal Entry, Is there any REST URL for JournalEntry to create ie POST operation?. 
If there is no REST for Journal entries, is there SOAP consuming guide to create journal entries?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood it, there is a url generated for your RESTlet script when you deploy it.  You can create a RESTlet for creating JE during POST, deploy it and call the generated URL from your external system.

Comment: Can you clarify little more on this?.  "there is a url generated for your RESTlet script when you deploy it" what/where to deploy? I am using java rest client to invoke the url.

Comment: @akb That means when you have written your restlet and deployed it you got one endpoint generated by netsuite which is nothing but an URL.

Comment: Rockstar is correct.  When you deploy your RESTlet in NetSuite, it should have a url that you can call externally.

Answer (score 0):

The rest url you are using is a standard from netsuite without any code of yours.
https://rest.netsuite.com/rest/roles

For other records, you need to create a restlet script and access it from your java application.

You can also use SOAP webservices. You can find documentation for those in netsuite.